# Formas de poder obtener los src de archivos en una carpeta local con js?

Tags: javascript

Se me ocurrió crear una variable con un `string` que contenga la `src` principal  ejem:"`musica/`" usar `input` file multiple y con un ciclo for a cada archivo seleccionado usar el nombre y completar la ruta de `src` para poder añadirlo a un reproductor de musica y que quede "`/musica/nombre de lacancion.mp3`" y poder pasarla a el reproductor de música.

Mi pregunta es.

> ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacer ese listado de direcciones de los
>   archivos con js?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que aquello que deseas realizar solo funcionaria bien si la ruta y los archivos donde guarda el usuario su musica coinciden... pero y si no coinciden?? ahi si que habrá problemas, otra cosa importante a tener en cuenta es que por razones de seguridad los navegadores jamas pero jamas de los nuncas te van a dar la ruta de los archivos, te darán siempre una fakepath, pero no la ruta original del archivo o carpeta, por esta razón deberias considerar una alternativa.

Comment: Se que eres nuevo asi que te invito a dar un paseo por el [tour] y a leer sobre [ask] para poder que puedas mejorar tu pregunta y a la vez nosotros ayudarte.

Comment: Un punto mas que puedes tener en cuenta es que realmente no necesitas guardar u obtener rutas de los archivos del usuario... simplemente necesitas la informacion de estos, la cual te la da los propios File que te arroja el input tipo file, esto quiere decir por ejemplo que puedes usar los tipo File que te arroja el input tipo file para poder construir imagenes, videos y hasta audio sin tener que usar rutas, cosa que puede llegar a solucionar el problema de las rutas, sin embargo seguro no tienes una idea clara de a que me refiero con usar los File para crear recursos... asi que.

Comment: Asi que te orientare un poco, considera leer sobre los metodos URL.createObjectURL y URL.revokeObjectURL, tambien por si acaso sobre FileReader, de hecho los primeros dos metodos te crean una ruta en base a los datos de un archivo, que podras usar libremente para tu reproductor en el src. Otro punto a tener en cuenta tambien para aclarar otra posible duda que tengas es, y si quiero usar la carpeta del usuario para guardar nueva musica??, respuesta, no se puede porque javascript no tiene acceso al sistema de archivos asi que no intentes obtener rutas para ese proposito.

Comment: a no, la musica que pondré solo estará en una ubicación,el usuario  solo podra pausar,adelantar y asi, ya me tope con lo del fakepath y se me ocurrio lo de seleccionar los archivos y crear la ruta con un ciclo completándola con el nombre

Comment: llegue a ver lo de URL.createObjectURL en otros foros, pero solo pase de el,entonces mirare mas y pruebo.gracias por responder

Comment: Como digo... debes considerar que el usuario puede no tener la misma ruta que tu y pues realmente la dirección como harías para completarla sin la información de fakepath que falta??, esa parte del fakepath no se puede obtener.

Comment: ah, el tipo de reproductor que queria hacer no era para que el usuario pueda reproducir su musica ,solo la que yo guarde en la carpeta ,pero como ya me dijiste que es posible usando esos metodos URLcreate y revoke tamien hare que se pueda hacer eso,ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si ya lo habrás resuelto, pero por si las dudas aquí un ejemplo de uso o aquello que puedes hacer para crear enlaces a tus recursos cuando no te sabes la ruta de la que provienen.

Decir que `URL.createObjectURL()` al igual que `URL.revokeObjectURL` son metodos sincronos y ademas son metodos instantaneos, por lo cual llegan a ser bastante utiles, entonces prosigamos con el ejemplo:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  
  //Obtenemos los elementos HTML.
  const inputFile = document.getElementById("inputFile");
  const audioSources = document.getElementById("audioSources");
  
  //Aqui tendras tus rutas disponibles (array de rutas de URL.createObjectURL).
  let fileUrls = [];
  
  function handleFiles(ev){
    
    //Reiniciamos cada vez para no guardar audios que no se usan.
    //No reinicies el array si no es el comportamiento que deseas.
    //Tampoco reinicies audioSources si no lo deseas.
    fileUrls = [];
    audioSources.innerHTML = "";
    
    //Obtenemos los archivos como un array (originalmente es un FileList).
    const files = Array.from(ev.currentTarget.files);
    
    //Podemos usar forEach puesto que hicimos Array.from...
    files.forEach((file, i) => {
      //Creamos un nuevo elemento audio para añadirlo posteriormente y ademas
      //Añadimos la nueva URL del recurso a la lista de URLS.
      const newSource = document.createElement("audio");
      fileUrls.push(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      
      //Cuando haya terminado de cargar podemos usar URL.revokeObjectURL
      //El audio seguira funcionando, debido a que ya cargo, configuramos tambien.
      //Las propiedades del audio para poder hacer uso de sus controles y que carguen
      //nuestro recurso.
      newSource.oncanplaytrough = ()=> URL.revokeObjectURL(fileUrls[i]);
      newSource.src = fileUrls[i];
      newSource.controls = "controls";
      
      //Agregamos los audios a nuestro contenedor de audios y adicionalmente ponemos un
      //Salto de linea al final.
      audioSources.appendChild(newSource);
      audioSources.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    });
    
  }
  
  //Se ejecuta cada vez que los archivos seleccionados cambian.
  inputFile.addEventListener("change", handleFiles);

}
```

```html
<input type = "file" accept = "audio/*" id = "inputFile" multiple>
<div id = "audioSources">
</div>
```

Esta es una manera de usar `URLs` de recursos a los cuales no tienes acceso a su ruta.

Comment: Notese que las rutas de los archivos almacenadas en  fileUrls solo podrán ser reusados si no usaste URL.revokeObjectURL, si deseas usar esa ruta en otra parte entonces deberás considerar no usar URL.revokeObjectURL hasta que dejes definitivamente de usar el recurso o el recurso solo lo vayas a usar en una sola parte (un solo audio), ya que aunque revoques el URL la data seguira cargada en el audio, pero si intentas usar una URL creada por URL.createObjectURL que posteriormente le hiciste un revoke en otra parte del codigo ya la data no podrá ser cargada recuerda esto.

Comment: Sip esto me ayuda, busque sobre URL.createObjectURL y encontre ejemplos raros que usaban  esto para previsualisar imagenes antes de enviarlas al servidor y hasta llague a obtener una url "blob:null/d172d9ad-2717-4a7b-824f-10e58d83efb9" recuerdo haberla probado poniendola en la src y no funcionar,aunque ahroa si .Pero en fin, gracias por el ejemplo ya pude lograr quitarme esa traba que tenia